# How to split ' ; ' separated CSV file in pandas after using read_csv() in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

I am trying to split the comma-separated column into 4 individual columns shown in the picture using split() but it's not working after importing CSV file. Can anyone please tell me how I can do it?

```
I want something like this:

sexe  preusuel  annais  nombre

1      A         1980     3

and so on....
```

Comment: `pd.read_csv(.... , sep = ';')`?

Comment: no, i already tried it's not working

Answer (score 3):

```
df = pd.read_csv('nat2018.csv', sep=';')
```

Should work for you.

Comment: Ah.. thank you i was using ' , '  IN PLACE OF ' ; '.

Answer (score 0):

Specify `delimiter=';'` in `read_csv` parameters.